# problema con :before en css

Tags: css, css3, diseño, pseudoelementos

[image: codigo]

los elementos del before no deberian mostrarse encima de la caja aunque la mitad de arriba sea del mismo color que el fondo?(me refiero a los dedos del tenedor azules oscuros)

Comment: El before y el after van dentro del elemento, antes y desúes (respectivamente) del contenido del mismo